# A proof of the existence of Villarceau circles with synthetic geometry

Tags: geometry

Given a point on a torus there exist exactly 4 circumferences that lie on the surface of the torus passing through that point. The two non-obvious ones are called Villarceau circles.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villarceau_circles) gives a proof of their existence with analytic geometry. I'm interested in a proof with synthetic geometry because of this anecdote by Emilio Segrè:

> On a different occasion, while I was waiting to be called to an oral examination, **Majorana gave me a synthetic proof for the existence of Villarceau's circles on a torus**. I did not fully understand it, but memorized it on the spot. As I entered the examination room, Professor Pittarelli asked me, as was his wont, whether I had prepared a special topic. "Yes, on Villarceau's circles," I said, and I proceeded immediately to repeat Majorana's words before I forgot them. The professor was impressed and congratulated me on such an elegant proof, which was new to him.

(From [here](http://publishing.cdlib.org/ucpressebooks/view?docId=ft700007rb&chunk.id=d0e600&toc.id=&brand=ucpress), emphasis mine)

Comment: I _could_ say that, although it doesn't answer this question, maybe this is a good occasion to mention that Wikipedia's [List of circle topics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_circle_topics) is a magnificent thing, the like of which might never have existed if Wikipedia, itself an unprecedented achievement, had not existed.  I _could_ say that, but since I'm the initial author of that article, I won't, but instead will merely say that if you're curious about this kind of geometry, you might find it of some value.

Comment: +1 for the question.  Often synthetic proofs shed intuitive light not found in analytic proofs (and probably vice-versa as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof can be found in *Anonymous* - **Section du tore par un plan tangent à cette surface et passant par son centre** in Nouvelle Annales de Mathématiques 1.18 (1859), pp. 258-261, which is available [here](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/NAM/NAM_1859_1_18_/NAM_1859_1_18__258_1/NAM_1859_1_18__258_1.pdf).

Comment: In the same vein, there is a simple synthetic proof of the Dandelin spheres theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandelin_spheres#Proof_that_the_curve_has_constant_sum_of_distances_to_foci).